# Shuffle array of arrays pyspark columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, shuffle

I have pyspark column Like this:

```
                   gm_array
[[1, 4, 6,...], [2, 7, 8,...], [3, 5, 7,...],...]
[[8, 11, 9,...], [7, 2, 6,...], [10, 9, 8,...],...]
[[90, 13, 67,...], [55, 6, 98,...], [1, 6, 2,...],...]
.
.
```

Now I want to shuffle this single array and also array inside this array, and then I want to pick 5 first element from first 5 array.

1st Out which is randomly shuffle array:

```
                  gm_array
[[19, 6, 1,...], [9, 80, 5,...], [30, 7, 3,...],...]
[[7, 9, 11,...], [6, 8, 7,...], [18, 7, 10,...],...]
[[90, 1, 7,...], [8, 9, 81,...], [6, 5, 1,...],...]
.
.
```

2nd Out 1st element of 1st 5 array inside main array:

```
[19, 9, 30,...]
[7, 6, 18,...]
[[90, 8, 6,...]
.
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using some array and higher-order functions you can do:

```py
import random
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# example of input dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ([[random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(6)],)
        for _ in range(4)
    ],
    ["gm_array"]
)

# first step: shuffle arrays
df_shuffled = df.withColumn(
    "gm_array",
    F.shuffle(F.transform("gm_array", lambda x: F.shuffle(x)))
)

# second step: pick top 5 elements
df_top_5 = df_shuffled.withColumn(
    "gm_array",
    F.transform(F.slice("gm_array", 1, 5), lambda x: x[0])
)

df_top_5.show(truncate=False)
#+--------------------+
#|gm_array            |
#+--------------------+
#|[77, 44, 6, 23, 100]|
#|[40, 57, 10, 32, 27]|
#|[3, 45, 17, 9, 9]   |
#|[62, 39, 10, 95, 17]|
#+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I came to know about `F.transform` method. Really handy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do it. using `shuffle` and `getItem(i)`

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
import joblib
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


data1 = [
    ["01001", 1, 5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400],
    ["01001", 2, 1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400],
    ["01003", 1, 5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400],
    ["01003", 2, 1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400],

      ]

df1Columns = ["county", "bin_number",   "age_group1",   "age_group2",   "t_group1_1",   "t_group2_1",   "t_group1_2",   "t_group2_2"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)

columns_list = list(df1.columns)
print(columns_list)

array_cols_concat = [   "age_group1",   "age_group2",   "t_group1_1",   "t_group2_1",   "t_group1_2",   "t_group2_2"]
df1_mod = df1.withColumn("single_array1", F.array(array_cols_concat))

df1_mod = df1_mod.withColumn("single_array2", F.shuffle(F.col("single_array1")))
df1_mod = df1_mod.withColumn("single_array3", F.shuffle(F.col("single_array1")))
df1_mod = df1_mod.withColumn("single_array4", F.shuffle(F.col("single_array1")))
df1_mod = df1_mod.withColumn("single_array5", F.shuffle(F.col("single_array1")))
df1_mod = df1_mod.withColumn("single_array6", F.shuffle(F.col("single_array1")))
df1_mod = df1_mod.withColumn("single_array7", F.shuffle(F.col("single_array1")))
df1_mod = df1_mod.withColumn("single_array8", F.shuffle(F.col("single_array1")))

array_cols_concat2 = ["single_array1", "single_array2", "single_array3", "single_array4", "single_array5", "single_array6", "single_array7", "single_array8"    ]

df2_mod = df1_mod.withColumn("nested_array", F.array(array_cols_concat2))

columns_list = df2_mod.columns
df2_mod = df2_mod.select("nested_array")
print("Dataframe prepared")
df2_mod.show(n=100, truncate=False)

df2_mod_shuffled = df2_mod.withColumn("shuffled_outer", F.shuffle(F.col("nested_array")))
print("Dataframe shuffled outer")
df2_mod_shuffled.show(n=100, truncate=False)

print("Select first 5 elements of the shuffled outer array")
df2_first3array = df2_mod_shuffled.withColumn("first_three", F.slice("shuffled_outer", start=1, length=3))
print("Dataframe first 3 selected")
df2_first3array.show(n=100, truncate=False)

colquery_array = []
for ii in range(3):
    colquery_array.append(F.shuffle(F.col("first_three")).getItem(ii).getItem(0))

df2_firstElementOfEach =  df2_first3array.withColumn("element_array", F.array(colquery_array)).select("element_array")
print("Dataframe first 3 selected")
df2_firstElementOfEach.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
Dataframe prepared
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|nested_array                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400], [10, 100, 400, 200, 300, 5], [5, 200, 100, 300, 10, 400], [5, 100, 10, 300, 400, 200], [5, 100, 200, 400, 10, 300], [5, 200, 100, 10, 300, 400], [300, 400, 5, 100, 200, 10], [5, 300, 10, 200, 400, 100]]|
|[[1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400], [2, 400, 200, 1, 300, 100], [100, 1, 300, 200, 2, 400], [300, 2, 200, 1, 400, 100], [300, 2, 1, 100, 200, 400], [1, 300, 200, 2, 100, 400], [2, 200, 100, 1, 400, 300], [100, 1, 300, 200, 2, 400]]        |
|[[5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400], [400, 300, 200, 100, 5, 10], [5, 100, 200, 10, 300, 400], [100, 10, 400, 200, 300, 5], [200, 10, 400, 300, 5, 100], [200, 400, 100, 300, 10, 5], [100, 300, 400, 10, 5, 200], [200, 100, 400, 5, 300, 10]]|
|[[1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400], [1, 200, 400, 2, 100, 300], [2, 400, 300, 100, 200, 1], [1, 400, 100, 300, 200, 2], [100, 200, 1, 300, 400, 2], [400, 2, 100, 1, 300, 200], [1, 400, 2, 200, 100, 300], [1, 2, 300, 100, 200, 400]]        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Dataframe shuffled outer
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|nested_array                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |shuffled_outer                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400], [10, 100, 400, 200, 300, 5], [5, 200, 100, 300, 10, 400], [5, 100, 10, 300, 400, 200], [5, 100, 200, 400, 10, 300], [5, 200, 100, 10, 300, 400], [300, 400, 5, 100, 200, 10], [5, 300, 10, 200, 400, 100]]|[[5, 200, 100, 10, 300, 400], [10, 100, 400, 200, 300, 5], [5, 200, 100, 300, 10, 400], [5, 100, 10, 300, 400, 200], [5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400], [5, 300, 10, 200, 400, 100], [5, 100, 200, 400, 10, 300], [300, 400, 5, 100, 200, 10]]|
|[[1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400], [2, 400, 200, 1, 300, 100], [100, 1, 300, 200, 2, 400], [300, 2, 200, 1, 400, 100], [300, 2, 1, 100, 200, 400], [1, 300, 200, 2, 100, 400], [2, 200, 100, 1, 400, 300], [100, 1, 300, 200, 2, 400]]        |[[1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400], [2, 400, 200, 1, 300, 100], [300, 2, 200, 1, 400, 100], [2, 200, 100, 1, 400, 300], [300, 2, 1, 100, 200, 400], [1, 300, 200, 2, 100, 400], [100, 1, 300, 200, 2, 400], [100, 1, 300, 200, 2, 400]]        |
|[[5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400], [400, 300, 200, 100, 5, 10], [5, 100, 200, 10, 300, 400], [100, 10, 400, 200, 300, 5], [200, 10, 400, 300, 5, 100], [200, 400, 100, 300, 10, 5], [100, 300, 400, 10, 5, 200], [200, 100, 400, 5, 300, 10]]|[[5, 100, 200, 10, 300, 400], [5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400], [200, 100, 400, 5, 300, 10], [100, 10, 400, 200, 300, 5], [200, 10, 400, 300, 5, 100], [100, 300, 400, 10, 5, 200], [200, 400, 100, 300, 10, 5], [400, 300, 200, 100, 5, 10]]|
|[[1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400], [1, 200, 400, 2, 100, 300], [2, 400, 300, 100, 200, 1], [1, 400, 100, 300, 200, 2], [100, 200, 1, 300, 400, 2], [400, 2, 100, 1, 300, 200], [1, 400, 2, 200, 100, 300], [1, 2, 300, 100, 200, 400]]        |[[1, 400, 2, 200, 100, 300], [1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400], [1, 2, 300, 100, 200, 400], [400, 2, 100, 1, 300, 200], [100, 200, 1, 300, 400, 2], [1, 400, 100, 300, 200, 2], [1, 200, 400, 2, 100, 300], [2, 400, 300, 100, 200, 1]]        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Select first 5 elements of the shuffled outer array
Dataframe first 3 selected
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|nested_array                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |shuffled_outer                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |first_three                                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400], [10, 100, 400, 200, 300, 5], [5, 200, 100, 300, 10, 400], [5, 100, 10, 300, 400, 200], [5, 100, 200, 400, 10, 300], [5, 200, 100, 10, 300, 400], [300, 400, 5, 100, 200, 10], [5, 300, 10, 200, 400, 100]]|[[5, 200, 100, 10, 300, 400], [10, 100, 400, 200, 300, 5], [5, 200, 100, 300, 10, 400], [5, 100, 10, 300, 400, 200], [5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400], [5, 300, 10, 200, 400, 100], [5, 100, 200, 400, 10, 300], [300, 400, 5, 100, 200, 10]]|[[5, 200, 100, 10, 300, 400], [10, 100, 400, 200, 300, 5], [5, 200, 100, 300, 10, 400]]|
|[[1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400], [2, 400, 200, 1, 300, 100], [100, 1, 300, 200, 2, 400], [300, 2, 200, 1, 400, 100], [300, 2, 1, 100, 200, 400], [1, 300, 200, 2, 100, 400], [2, 200, 100, 1, 400, 300], [100, 1, 300, 200, 2, 400]]        |[[1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400], [2, 400, 200, 1, 300, 100], [300, 2, 200, 1, 400, 100], [2, 200, 100, 1, 400, 300], [300, 2, 1, 100, 200, 400], [1, 300, 200, 2, 100, 400], [100, 1, 300, 200, 2, 400], [100, 1, 300, 200, 2, 400]]        |[[1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400], [2, 400, 200, 1, 300, 100], [300, 2, 200, 1, 400, 100]]   |
|[[5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400], [400, 300, 200, 100, 5, 10], [5, 100, 200, 10, 300, 400], [100, 10, 400, 200, 300, 5], [200, 10, 400, 300, 5, 100], [200, 400, 100, 300, 10, 5], [100, 300, 400, 10, 5, 200], [200, 100, 400, 5, 300, 10]]|[[5, 100, 200, 10, 300, 400], [5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400], [200, 100, 400, 5, 300, 10], [100, 10, 400, 200, 300, 5], [200, 10, 400, 300, 5, 100], [100, 300, 400, 10, 5, 200], [200, 400, 100, 300, 10, 5], [400, 300, 200, 100, 5, 10]]|[[5, 100, 200, 10, 300, 400], [5, 10, 200, 100, 300, 400], [200, 100, 400, 5, 300, 10]]|
|[[1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400], [1, 200, 400, 2, 100, 300], [2, 400, 300, 100, 200, 1], [1, 400, 100, 300, 200, 2], [100, 200, 1, 300, 400, 2], [400, 2, 100, 1, 300, 200], [1, 400, 2, 200, 100, 300], [1, 2, 300, 100, 200, 400]]        |[[1, 400, 2, 200, 100, 300], [1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400], [1, 2, 300, 100, 200, 400], [400, 2, 100, 1, 300, 200], [100, 200, 1, 300, 400, 2], [1, 400, 100, 300, 200, 2], [1, 200, 400, 2, 100, 300], [2, 400, 300, 100, 200, 1]]        |[[1, 400, 2, 200, 100, 300], [1, 2, 100, 200, 300, 400], [1, 2, 300, 100, 200, 400]]   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Dataframe first 3 selected
+-------------+
|element_array|
+-------------+
|[5, 5, 10]   |
|[300, 300, 1]|
|[200, 5, 200]|
|[1, 1, 1]    |
+-------------+
```